# No transform between base_footprint and base_link

Tags: ros, create-autonomy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an URDF file with a fixed joint between base_footprint & base_link, but robot_state_publisher isn't publishing a tf transform between those 2 links. My understanding is that robot_state_publisher will publish & latch a static transform for fixed joints, but I'm not seeing it in any of my tests.

Details:

My base is irobot create2, using the create_autonomy base; source here: https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy

The URDF file has this snippet:

```
<joint name="base_footprint_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.017" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <parent link="base_footprint" />
  <child link="base_link" />
</joint>
```

I can't [yet] upload pictures, but my rqt_tf_tree shows: odom => base_footprint; and base_link => [ left_wheel_link, camera_link, right_wheel_link ]

(I added the base_link => camera_link transform using a static_transform_publisher; it's not in the create_autonomy URDF file.)

I can work around this, but I'm puzzled, and would like to find & fix the bug.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249766/no-transform-between-base_footprint-and-base_link/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2016-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

False alarm -- it's working. I tried various debugging tools and learned the pros & cons of each. Here's what I tried:

- `rosrun tf view_frames` doesn't show a link in frames.pdf (thus my confusion)
- `rosrun tf tf_echo base_footprint base_link` does show a link, at time 0.000
- `rosrun tf tf_monitor base_footprint base_link` does show a link, with `unknown_publisher`
- Rviz shows the hierarchy correctly

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
Hm. The fact that `view_frames` doesn't show it is troubling. Could [ros/geometry#136](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/136) be related?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-01-02**:
Ah, quite likely. Thanks for the link; it's good to know that this is a regression vs. expected behavior. Also [ros/geometry#117](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/117)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might help for now.

There was a recent update to view_frames. I ran into the same issue and used a work-around proposed [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/136#issue-194784610) by setting use_tf_static to false to the robot_state_publisher node .

```
 <arg name="use_tf_static" default="false"/> 
 <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" >
          <param name="use_tf_static" value="$(arg use_tf_static)"/>
 </node>
```

---

Originally posted by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) with karma: 120 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4